Как правильно добавлять/изменять динамические данные в gui типа pyqt5
Хочу сделать что-то типа торгового терминала криптобиржи для себя. Делаю стакан(orderbook), почти все работает, но нагрузка на процессор начинает быстро расти, с ростом новых строк в таблице gui. Может нужно иначе менять данные или этот pyqt5 не подходит для обмена большим кол-вом данных? Данные подгружаются через стрим, обрабатываются и распределяются по строкам в таблице. Может кто подскажет в какую сторону копать? Просто любой крипто терминал обрабатывает очень много стаканов и ведет себя нормально относительно нагрузки, а у меня от одного стакана нагрузка перегружает процессор до торможения и зависания программы. Если увеличить интервал на подгрузку данных в таблицу будет тоже самое, только через более длительное время. Сильно не ругайте, я новичок.
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        desktop_width = QApplication.desktop().width()
        desktop_height = QApplication.desktop().height()
        self.sorted_ob_a = {}
        self.sorted_ob_b = {}
        self.is_first = True
        window_width = 500
        window_height = 800
        
        ax = desktop_width // 2 - window_width // 2
        ay = desktop_height // 2 - window_height // 2

        self.setWindowTitle("Терминал для торговли")
        self.setGeometry(ax, ay, window_width, window_height)

        self.table = OrderBookTable(parent=self)

        self.thread = MyThread(self.table)
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.mysignal.connect(self.get_data)

    def get_data(self, l_ob): 

        if self.is_first == True:  
            self.sorted_ob_a = l_ob[0] 
            self.sorted_ob_b = l_ob[1] 
            step_asset = int(0.010*1000)
        
            start_price = 0
            end_price = 0
            
            
            for key, value in self.sorted_ob_a.items():
                end_price = int(float(key)*1000)
            
            for key, value in self.sorted_ob_b.items():
                if start_price == 0:
                    start_price = int(float(key)*1000)
                

            l_prices = [format(price/1000, '.3f') for price in range(start_price, end_price, step_asset)]
            #
            
            for row in l_prices:
                item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('0')
                item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem('0')
                item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(row))
                item3.setData(row, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
                
                self.table.sti.appendRow([item1, item2, item3])

            self.table.sti.sort(2, order=QtCore.Qt.SortOrder.DescendingOrder)
            self.table.setModel(self.table.sti)
            self.table.setColumnWidth(1, 70)
            self.table.setColumnWidth(2, 70)
            self.table.resize(500, 800)
            self.is_first = False
        else:
            # print('Im here')
            self.sorted_ob_a = l_ob[0] 
            self.sorted_ob_b = l_ob[1] 

            for key, value in self.sorted_ob_a.items():
                l_items = self.table.sti.findItems(str(key), column=2)
                if len(l_items) > 0:
                    item_row = l_items[0].row()
                    self.table.sti.takeRow(item_row)
                    item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('ask')
                    item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                    item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(key))
                    item3.setData(key, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
                    item3.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(209, 151, 144))
                    self.table.sti.insertRow(item_row, [item1, item2, item3])
                else:
                    item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('ask')
                    item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                    item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(key))
                    item3.setData(key, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
                    item3.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(209, 151, 144))
                    self.table.sti.appendRow([item1, item2, item3])

            for key, value in self.sorted_ob_b.items():
                l_items = self.table.sti.findItems(str(key), column=2)
                if len(l_items) > 0:
                    item_row = l_items[0].row()
                    self.table.sti.takeRow(item_row)
                    item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('bid')
                    item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                    item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(key))
                    item3.setData(key, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
                    item3.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(144, 209, 162))
                    self.table.sti.insertRow(item_row, [item1, item2, item3])
                else:
                    item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('bid')
                    item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                    item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(key))
                    item3.setData(key, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
                    item3.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(144, 209, 162))
                    
                    self.table.sti.appendRow([item1, item2, item3])
                    
            self.table.sti.sort(2, order=QtCore.Qt.SortOrder.DescendingOrder)
            self.table.setModel(self.table.sti)
            self.table.resize(500, 800)

class OrderBookTable(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.sti = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.sti.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Направление', 'Кол-во', 'Цена'])


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    def __init__(self, table: OrderBookTable):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = table
        self.running = False 

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        self.isFirst = True
        url = 'wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/bnbusdt@depth'
        json_result = []
        
        order_book_a = {}
        order_book_b = {}
        prev_u = 0
        count = 0
        threading.Thread(target=Binance_FStream, args=(url, json_result), daemon=True).start()
        client = None
        print('Started')
        while self.running:
            
            if client == None:
                client = Binance_API_F(api_key=keys.api_key, secret_key=keys.secret_key)
                snapshot_result = client.get_depth('bnbusdt', 50)
                lastUpdateId = snapshot_result['lastUpdateId']

                for i in snapshot_result['asks']:
                    order_book_a[i[0]] = i[1]
                for i in snapshot_result['bids']:
                    order_book_b[i[0]] = i[1]

                for i in json_result:
                    # print("u = ", i['u'], "U = ", i['U'], "lastUpdateId = ", lastUpdateId)
                    if i['u'] <= lastUpdateId:
                        json_result.remove(i)
                        prev_u = lastUpdateId
                        
                print('First Start Client!')

                sorted_ob_a = dict(sorted(order_book_a.items()))
                sorted_ob_b = dict(sorted(order_book_b.items()))
                l_ob = [sorted_ob_a, sorted_ob_b]
                self.mysignal.emit(l_ob)

            else:
                if self.isFirst == True:
                
                    for i in json_result:
                        # print("u = ", i['u'], "pu = ", i['pu'], "lastUpdateId = ", lastUpdateId)
                        
                        if i['U'] <= lastUpdateId +1 <= i['u']:
                            print('WE ARE IN LASTUPDATE +1')
                            for j in i['a']:
                                order_book_a[j[0]] = j[1]
                            for j in i['b']:
                                order_book_b[j[0]] = j[1]
                            prev_u = i['u']
                            json_result.remove(i)

                    self.isFirst = False
                else:

                    for i in json_result:
                        count = 0
                        if i['pu'] == prev_u:
                            count += 1
                            print('Im here')
                            print(len(json_result))
                            for j in i['a']:
                                order_book_a[j[0]] = j[1]
                            for j in i['b']:
                                order_book_b[j[0]] = j[1]
                            prev_u = i['u']
                            json_result.remove(i)
                    if count == 0:
                        client = None
                        self.isFirst = True
                    

                sorted_ob_a = dict(sorted(order_book_a.items()))
                sorted_ob_b = dict(sorted(order_book_b.items()))
                l_ob = [sorted_ob_a, sorted_ob_b]
                self.mysignal.emit(l_ob)

            time.sleep(0.5)

